# Magento 2 - css source maps not working

Tags: magento2, css, less, grunt, magento2.3.4

I created a new theme which extends from magento luma. I try to develope with less instead of css.

I need to enable CSS Source maps, so that I can debug my less, it helps to see in which less files the css of certain elements are stored, otherwise It will only show "styles-l.css" or "styles-m.css".

[image]

I followed the steps from the [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html).

What I did:

1. enabled css source maps in chrome.
2. Enabled "Server-side Less compilation" in magento backend
3. Added my theme **company_base** to **local-themes.js**:

**dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

'use strict';

/**
 * Define Themes
 *
 * area: area, one of (frontend|adminhtml|doc),
 * name: theme name in format Vendor/theme-name,
 * locale: locale,
 * files: [
 * 'css/styles-m',
 * 'css/styles-l'
 * ],
 * dsl: dynamic stylesheet language (less|sass)
 *
 */
module.exports = {
    company_base: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Company/Base',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
};
```

4. Executed `grunt exec`
5. Executed `grunt less`
6. Executed `grunt clean`
7. Executed `php bin/magento cache:flush full_page`
8. Executed `grunt watch`
9. Then I opened chrome developer tools and inspected some elements, but it still shows "styles-l.css" instead of the actual .less filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The sourcemaps where generated correctly, but in the wrong folder, since I configured my theme incorrectly in **dev/tools/grunt/configs/local-themes.js**:

**Before:**

```
module.exports = {
    company_base: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'Company/Base',
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
};
```

**After:**

```
module.exports = {
    company_base: {
        area: 'frontend',
        name: 'company/base',       // <-- I had to change it to lower case
        locale: 'de_DE',
        files: [
            'css/styles-m',
            'css/styles-l'
        ],
        dsl: 'less'
    },
};
```

Open the file **registration.php** of your theme and check your path:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/company/base', __DIR__);
```

As you cans see I used **company/base** but in my **local-theme.js** I used **Company/Base** as *name*.

---

> **NOTE**:  Never execute `grunt clean` **AFTER** all the other grunt commands,
>   since this will delete **pub/static/frontend/*** and the changes from
>   `grunt exec` and `grunt less` get lost.

Answer (score 15):

In magento 2.4.4 I had same problem. I fixed it by downgrading to

```
"grunt-contrib-less": "1.4.1"
```

in package.json and running npm install again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vince. It's really helpful.

Comment: Yes! I've been fighting this issue since yesterday. Downgrading "grunt-contrib-less" to the suggested version did fix the issue! Then I just ran grunt commands as usual and source-maps were generated normally. Thank you!

Comment: Awesome answer Vince, saved me for losing my mind.

Answer (score 1):

With magento 2.4.x I get the issue and I resolved it by turn off Sign Static Files

```
Go to backend > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Sign Static Files > set to NO
```

then flush cache.

Comment: I need to try this asap thx

Answer (score 1):

As this question pops up when searching 'magento 2 source maps not working' I'll add another possible case, I couldn't find anything online about it.

Your store can have different locale compared to specified in `local-themes.js` (or elsewhere).

I had this situation trying to get source maps working with Luma theme, my store has ru_RU locale while Luma in `local-themes.js` has en_US, as a result source maps weren't generated in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/ru_RU/css`.

Fixed it by creating new theme definition in `local-themes.js`:

```
luma_ru: {
    area: 'frontend',
    name: 'Magento/luma',
    locale: 'ru_RU',
    files: [
        'css/styles-m',
        'css/styles-l'
    ],
    dsl: 'less'
},
```